# Replace tabs with pipe delimiter

Tags: python

I have a tab delimited file that I need to have pipe delimited. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I'm very new to python, so I have not tried anything. Google has not done me well on this one. I've been doing a find/replace within Notepadd ++.

What I'm getting:

```
A   0MT0371755  I       ZZTEST  PERSON          NP  2015-12-15
```

Expected:

```
A|0MT0371755|I||ZZTEST|PERSON|||NP|2015-12-15|
```

Comment: Why did you tag with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest/best way is to use the `.replace()` method on strings:

```
input_text = "A\t0MT0371755\tI\tZZTEST\tPERSON\tNP\t2015-12-15"
output_text = input_text.replace('\t', '|')  # \t is a tab character
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we can try using `re.sub`:

```
input = "A\t0MT0371755\tI\tZZTEST\tPERSON\tNP\t2015-12-15"
input = re.sub(r'\t', '|', input)
```

On Notepad++, just search in regex mode for `\t` and then replace with `|`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('file.in', 'r') as orig, open('file.out', 'w') as out:
  out.write(orig.read().replace('\t', '|'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina, I have done that, but frankly can't see what my answer is missing other than a (imho) pointless "The simplest/best way is to use the `.replace()` method on strings:" Is there anything specific you think I should learn to provide the best help?